# Why does SBT want to get org.scala-sbt while it has already been installed?

Tags: java, macos, scala, sbt, homebrew

I installed `sbt` using `brew install sbt` on Mac OS.

And the `build.sbt` file for my app looks like this:

```
import NativePackagerKeys._

packageArchetype.java_application

name := """scala-getting-started"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.twitter" % "finagle-http_2.10" % "6.18.0",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.0-801.jdbc4"
)
```

What I really cannot understand is that `sbt` needs to get package `org.scala-sbt` if I want to compile the current app.

```
Hanfeis-MacBook-Pro:scala-getting-started hanfeisun$ sbt compile stage
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.5 ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/jars/sbt.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5!sbt.jar (7322ms)
```

Shouldn't `org.scala-sbt` already been installed when I install `sbt` by `brew install sbt`? Why does `sbt` need to download the package of itself again?

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does sbt need to download the package of itself again?

Because you can easily change [SBT version](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Hello.html#Setting+the+sbt+version), it has to be able to download JAR files for different SBT versions. So what you actually install is just a shell script which knows how to retrieve SBT launcher if it isn't already, and how to launch it if it is.